# Java for Android Null Pointer Exception on IInAppBillingService.getSkuDetails

Tags: java, android, json, in-app-billing

When I run the below Java for Android code, I get a NullPointerException on the line that calls getSkuDetails in the doInBackground method in the GetItemList class. But when I step through in the debugger, all the parameters to getSkuDetails have values. pName is not an empty string and querySkus has two items in it. The exact error message I'm getting is "Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.Bundle com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService.getSkuDetails(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)' on a null object reference." Does anyone know why?

```
package com.myknitcards;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AvailableCards extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_available_cards);
    String packagename = this.getPackageName();
    TextView priceView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.availablePrice);
    new GetItemList(packagename, priceView).execute();
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.available_cards, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}

class GetItemList extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Long> {

private String pName;
private TextView pView;

GetItemList(String packagename, TextView priceView){
    pName = packagename;
    pView = priceView;
}

IInAppBillingService mService;

ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
   @Override
   public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
       mService = null;
   }

   @Override
   public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name,
      IBinder service) {
       mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
   }
};

@Override
protected Long doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String> ();
    skuList.add("i001");
    skuList.add("i002");
    Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
    querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);
    Bundle skuDetails = null;
    try {
        skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, pName, "inapp", querySkus);
        int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
        if (response == 0) {
           ArrayList<String> responseList
              = skuDetails.getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");
           for (String thisResponse : responseList) {
              JSONObject object;
              object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
              String sku = object.getString("productId");
              String price = object.getString("price");
              String mFirstIntermediate;
              String mSecondIntermediate;
            if (sku.equals("i001")) mFirstIntermediate = price;
              else if (sku.equals("i002")) mSecondIntermediate = price;
            pView.setText(sku + ": " + price);
           }
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException ne)  {
        Log.d("Synch Billing", "Error Null Pointer: " + ne.getMessage());
        ne.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("Synch Billing", "Error Remote: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (JSONException je) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("Synch Billing", "Error JSON: " + je.getMessage());
        je.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Here's my log:

```
01-25 19:02:18.888: D/AndroidRuntime(4802): >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
01-25 19:02:18.894: D/AndroidRuntime(4802): CheckJNI is OFF

01-25 19:02:18.951: D/ICU(4802): No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
01-25 19:02:19.016: I/Radio-JNI(4802): register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
01-25 19:02:19.048: D/AndroidRuntime(4802): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
01-25 19:02:19.054: I/art(4802): System.exit called, status: 0
01-25 19:02:19.055: I/AndroidRuntime(4802): VM exiting with result code 0.
01-25 19:02:19.904: D/AndroidRuntime(4816): >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
01-25 19:02:19.911: D/AndroidRuntime(4816): CheckJNI is OFF
01-25 19:02:19.969: D/ICU(4816): No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
01-25 19:02:20.030: I/Radio-JNI(4816): register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
01-25 19:02:20.061: D/AndroidRuntime(4816): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
01-25 19:02:20.065: I/ActivityManager(607): Force stopping com.myknitcards appid=10087 user=-1: set debug app
01-25 19:02:20.066: I/ActivityManager(607): Killing 4727:com.myknitcards/u0a87 (adj 7): stop com.myknitcards
01-25 19:02:20.077: D/GraphicsStats(607): Buffer count: 3
01-25 19:02:20.077: I/WindowState(607): WIN DEATH: Window{9799d39 u0 com.myknitcards/com.myknitcards.MyKnitCardsMain}
01-25 19:02:20.179: I/ActivityManager(607):   Force finishing activity ActivityRecord{16bdee6 u0 com.myknitcards/.MyKnitCardsMain t53}
01-25 19:02:20.182: W/ActivityManager(607): Spurious death for ProcessRecord{d0de1a6 0:com.myknitcards/u0a87}, curProc for 4727: null
01-25 19:02:20.183: I/ActivityManager(607): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.myknitcards/.MyKnitCardsMain} from uid 2000 on display 0
01-25 19:02:20.195: D/AndroidRuntime(4816): Shutting down VM
01-25 19:02:20.226: I/ActivityManager(607): Start proc 4826:com.myknitcards/u0a87 for activity com.myknitcards/.MyKnitCardsMain
01-25 19:02:20.233: I/art(4826): Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
01-25 19:02:20.272: E/art(4826): Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
01-25 19:02:20.272: I/art(4826): Debugger is no longer active
01-25 19:02:20.292: W/ActivityThread(4826): Application com.myknitcards is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
01-25 19:02:20.293: I/System.out(4826): Sending WAIT chunk
01-25 19:02:20.341: I/OpenGLRenderer(607): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-25 19:02:21.296: I/art(4826): Debugger is active
01-25 19:02:21.495: I/System.out(4826): Debugger has connected
01-25 19:02:21.495: I/System.out(4826): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-25 19:02:21.695: I/System.out(4826): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-25 19:02:21.895: I/System.out(4826): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-25 19:02:22.096: I/System.out(4826): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-25 19:02:22.297: I/System.out(4826): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-25 19:02:22.498: I/System.out(4826): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-25 19:02:22.698: I/System.out(4826): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-25 19:02:22.898: I/System.out(4826): debugger has settled (1457)
01-25 19:02:22.975: W/System(4826): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.myknitcards-1/lib/arm
01-25 19:02:23.044: D/OpenGLRenderer(4826): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
01-25 19:02:23.076: D/Finsky(1556): [101] InAppBillingUtils.getPreferredAccount: com.myknitcards: Account from first account - [j5w9pVwTyqMNo_FRNWfkXIUz9SE]
01-25 19:02:23.080: D/Finsky(1556): [143] InAppBillingUtils.getPreferredAccount: com.myknitcards: Account from first account - [j5w9pVwTyqMNo_FRNWfkXIUz9SE]
01-25 19:02:23.084: D/com.myknitcards(4826): In-app Billing is set up OK
01-25 19:02:23.105: I/Adreno-EGL(4826): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/21/15, 369a2ea, I96aee987eb
01-25 19:02:23.108: I/OpenGLRenderer(4826): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-25 19:02:23.133: W/AppOps(607): Finishing op nesting under-run: uid 1000 pkg android code 24 time=1451855407389 duration=1783 nesting=0
01-25 19:02:23.222: I/ActivityManager(607): Displayed com.myknitcards/.MyKnitCardsMain: +3s7ms
01-25 19:02:23.225: I/Keyboard.Facilitator(1004): onFinishInput()
01-25 19:02:23.231: D/WifiStateMachine(607): starting scan for "BooNetwork-5G"WPA_PSK with 2462,5785
01-25 19:02:24.523: D/audio_hw_primary(196): out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) kvpairs: routing=2
01-25 19:02:24.524: I/ActivityManager(607): START u0 {cmp=com.myknitcards/.AvailableCards} from uid 10087 on display 0
01-25 19:02:24.533: D/audio_hw_primary(196): select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: none)
01-25 19:02:24.533: D/ACDB-LOADER(196): ACDB -> send_afe_cal
01-25 19:02:24.533: D/audio_hw_primary(196): enable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
01-25 19:02:24.542: D/audio_hw_primary(196): enable_audio_route: apply and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
01-25 19:02:24.666: I/ActivityManager(607): Displayed com.myknitcards/.AvailableCards: +134ms
01-25 19:02:24.667: I/Keyboard.Facilitator(1004): onFinishInput()
01-25 19:02:24.719: D/OpenGLRenderer(4826): endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb388d500 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb36fe690
01-25 19:02:27.777: D/audio_hw_primary(196): disable_audio_route: reset and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
01-25 19:02:27.778: D/audio_hw_primary(196): disable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
01-25 19:02:31.524: D/Synch Billing(4826): Error Null Pointer: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.Bundle com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService.getSkuDetails(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)' on a null object reference
01-25 19:02:34.741: W/System.err(4826): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.Bundle com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService.getSkuDetails(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)' on a null object reference
01-25 19:02:34.742: W/System.err(4826):     at com.myknitcards.GetItemList.doInBackground(AvailableCards.java:87)
01-25 19:02:34.742: W/System.err(4826):     at com.myknitcards.GetItemList.doInBackground(AvailableCards.java:1)
01-25 19:02:34.742: W/System.err(4826):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
01-25 19:02:34.743: W/System.err(4826):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-25 19:02:34.743: W/System.err(4826):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
01-25 19:02:34.743: W/System.err(4826):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
01-25 19:02:34.743: W/System.err(4826):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
01-25 19:02:34.743: W/System.err(4826):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
01-25 19:02:38.949: W/art(4826): Debugger told VM to exit with status 1
01-25 19:02:39.025: D/GraphicsStats(607): Buffer count: 3
01-25 19:02:39.026: I/WindowState(607): WIN DEATH: Window{f33f18e u0 com.myknitcards/com.myknitcards.MyKnitCardsMain}
01-25 19:02:39.029: I/WindowState(607): WIN DEATH: Window{6d143a7 u0 com.myknitcards/com.myknitcards.AvailableCards}
01-25 19:02:39.047: I/Zygote(206): Process 4826 exited cleanly (1)
01-25 19:02:39.066: I/ActivityManager(607): Process com.myknitcards (pid 4826) has died
01-25 19:02:39.068: W/ActivityManager(607): Force removing ActivityRecord{d4915cb u0 com.myknitcards/.AvailableCards t54}: app died, no saved state
01-25 19:02:39.080: I/ActivityManager(607): Start proc 4874:com.myknitcards/u0a87 for activity com.myknitcards/.MyKnitCardsMain
01-25 19:02:39.100: I/art(4874): Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
01-25 19:02:39.157: W/System(4874): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.myknitcards-1/lib/arm
01-25 19:02:39.223: D/OpenGLRenderer(4874): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
01-25 19:02:39.264: I/Adreno-EGL(4874): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/21/15, 369a2ea, I96aee987eb
01-25 19:02:39.267: I/OpenGLRenderer(4874): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-25 19:02:39.342: D/Finsky(1556): [100] InAppBillingUtils.getPreferredAccount: com.myknitcards: Account from first account - [j5w9pVwTyqMNo_FRNWfkXIUz9SE]
01-25 19:02:39.346: D/Finsky(1556): [101] InAppBillingUtils.getPreferredAccount: com.myknitcards: Account from first account - [j5w9pVwTyqMNo_FRNWfkXIUz9SE]
01-25 19:02:39.347: D/com.myknitcards(4874): In-app Billing is set up OK
01-25 19:02:39.404: I/ActivityManager(607): Displayed com.myknitcards/.MyKnitCardsMain: +335ms
01-25 19:02:39.404: W/InputMethodManagerService(607): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 4826 uid 10087
01-25 19:02:39.412: I/Keyboard.Facilitator(1004): onFinishInput()
01-25 19:02:40.885: D/audio_hw_primary(196): out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) kvpairs: routing=2
01-25 19:02:40.888: I/ActivityManager(607): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher (has extras)} from uid 1000 on display 0
01-25 19:02:40.895: D/audio_hw_primary(196): select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: none)
01-25 19:02:40.895: D/ACDB-LOADER(196): ACDB -> send_afe_cal
01-25 19:02:40.895: D/audio_hw_primary(196): enable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
01-25 19:02:40.905: D/audio_hw_primary(196): enable_audio_route: apply and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
01-25 19:02:41.013: I/Keyboard.Facilitator(1004): onFinishInput()
01-25 19:02:41.014: I/art(607): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 25641(1654KB) AllocSpace objects, 19(376KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 18MB/27MB, paused 2.227ms total 106.933ms
01-25 19:02:41.560: W/OpenGLRenderer(1111): Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
01-25 19:02:41.560: W/OpenGLRenderer(1111): Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
01-25 19:02:43.233: D/WifiStateMachine(607): starting scan for "BooNetwork-5G"WPA_PSK with 2462,5785
01-25 19:02:43.616: I/PowerManagerService(607): Going to sleep due to lid switch (uid 1000)...
01-25 19:02:43.616: I/PowerManagerService(607): Sleeping (uid 1000)...
01-25 19:02:43.621: W/AudioPolicyIntefaceImpl(196): getOutputForAttr uid 10012 tried to pass itself off as 1000
01-25 19:02:43.622: W/AudioFlinger(196): uid 10012 tried to pass itself off as 1000
01-25 19:02:43.625: I/Keyboard.Facilitator(1004): onFinishInput()
01-25 19:02:43.632: D/audio_hw_primary(196): out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) kvpairs: routing=2
01-25 19:02:43.698: I/ActivityManager(607): Config changes=480 {1.0 310mcc?mnc en_US ldltr sw600dp w960dp h528dp 320dpi lrg land finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.6}
01-25 19:02:43.700: I/InputReader(607): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
01-25 19:02:43.700: I/InputReader(607): Device reconfigured: id=6, name='elan-touchscreen', size 1200x1920, orientation 1, mode 1, display id 0
01-25 19:02:43.703: V/AudioService.RotationHelper(607): publishing device rotation =1 (x90deg)
01-25 19:02:43.707: D/audio_hw_primary(196): adev_set_parameters: enter: rotation=90
01-25 19:02:44.040: D/Launcher.Model(1111): DbDebug    Modify item (Play Music) in db, id: 4 (2, 0, 0, 0) --> (2, 0, 0, 0)
01-25 19:02:44.040: D/Launcher.Model(1111): DbDebug    Modify item (Play Books) in db, id: 6 (2, 0, 1, 0) --> (2, 0, 1, 0)
01-25 19:02:44.041: D/Launcher.Model(1111): DbDebug    Modify item (Play Movies & TV) in db, id: 8 (2, 0, 2, 0) --> (2, 0, 2, 0)
01-25 19:02:44.041: D/Launcher.Model(1111): DbDebug    Modify item (Play Games) in db, id: 10 (2, 0, 3, 0) --> (2, 0, 3, 0)
01-25 19:02:44.042: D/Launcher.Model(1111): DbDebug    Modify item (Play Newsstand) in db, id: 12 (2, 0, 0, 1) --> (2, 0, 0, 1)
01-25 19:02:44.042: D/Launcher.Model(1111): DbDebug    Modify item (Google+) in db, id: 14 (2, 0, 1, 1) --> (2, 0, 1, 1)
01-25 19:02:44.043: D/Launcher.Model(1111): DbDebug    Modify item (Keep) in db, id: 16 (2, 0, 2, 1) --> (2, 0, 2, 1)
01-25 19:02:44.043: D/Launcher.Model(1111): DbDebug    Modify item (Calendar) in db, id: 20 (2, 0, 3, 1) --> (2, 0, 3, 1)
01-25 19:02:44.043: D/Launcher.Model(1111): DbDebug    Modify item (Currents) in db, id: 22 (2, 0, 0, 2) --> (2, 0, 0, 2)
01-25 19:02:44.044: D/Launcher.Model(1111): DbDebug    Modify item (Photos) in db, id: 24 (2, 0, 1, 2) --> (2, 0, 1, 2)
01-25 19:02:44.044: D/Launcher.Model(1111): DbDebug    Modify item (Earth) in db, id: 26 (2, 0, 2, 2) --> (2, 0, 2, 2)
01-25 19:02:44.147: I/Keyboard.Facilitator(1004): onFinishInput()
01-25 19:02:44.190: I/Launcher(1111): Deferring update until onResume
01-25 19:02:44.191: I/Launcher(1111): Deferring update until onResume
01-25 19:02:44.202: I/WindowManager(607): Screen frozen for +551ms due to Window{b92ff9b u0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}
01-25 19:02:44.222: V/KeyguardServiceDelegate(607): onScreenTurnedOff()
01-25 19:02:44.249: I/DisplayManagerService(607): Display device changed state: "Built-in Screen", OFF
01-25 19:02:44.249: D/SurfaceFlinger(188): Set power mode=0, type=0 flinger=0xb6aa4000
01-25 19:02:44.529: D/SurfaceControl(607): Excessive delay in setPowerMode(): 280ms
01-25 19:02:44.530: E/ANDR-PERF-LOCK(204): Failed to apply optimization for resource: 4 level: 0
01-25 19:02:44.540: D/audio_hw_primary(196): adev_set_parameters: enter: screen_state=off
01-25 19:02:44.545: W/qcom_sensors_hal(607): hal_acquire_resources, no active sensors!
01-25 19:02:44.554: E/native(607): do suspend true
01-25 19:02:44.580: D/PhoneStatusBar(705): disable: < expand ICONS* alerts SYSTEM_INFO* back home recent clock search quick_settings >
01-25 19:02:44.721: D/PhoneStatusBar(705): disable: < expand ICONS alerts SYSTEM_INFO back HOME* RECENT* clock SEARCH* quick_settings >
01-25 19:02:46.209: I/art(607): Starting a blocking GC Explicit
01-25 19:02:46.280: I/art(607): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 14241(923KB) AllocSpace objects, 8(160KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 17MB/26MB, paused 1.129ms total 70.343ms
01-25 19:02:46.953: D/audio_hw_primary(196): disable_audio_route: reset and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
01-25 19:02:46.953: D/audio_hw_primary(196): disable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
01-25 19:03:03.251: D/WifiStateMachine(607): L2Connected CMD_START_SCAN source -2 41, 42 -> obsolete
01-25 19:03:03.787: E/NetlinkEvent(192): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
01-25 19:03:14.835: E/NetlinkEvent(192): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
01-25 19:03:29.947: E/NetlinkEvent(192): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
01-25 19:03:41.038: E/(193): invalid crash request of size 4 (from pid=4794 uid=0)
01-25 19:03:41.165: E/Diag_Lib(4962):  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 2
01-25 19:03:41.166: E/Sensors(4962): sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush failed, 9
01-25 19:03:41.166: E/Sensors(4962): sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush failed, 9
01-25 19:03:41.198: W/Sensors(4962): sns_smr_la.c(446):smr_la: smr_apps_la_thread_main is starting, fd=11, sns_smr.en_rx_msg_ptr=b6f34a08
01-25 19:03:41.261: W/Sensors(4962): sns_sam_app.c(6827):sns_sam_reg_algo: Registering algo service 16, err 0
01-25 19:03:41.272: E/Sensors(4962): sns_debug_main.c(565):Debug Config File missing in EFS!
01-25 19:03:44.187: I/Keyboard.Facilitator.LanguageModelFlusher(1004): run()
01-25 19:03:44.188: I/Keyboard.Facilitator(1004): flushDynamicLanguageModels()
01-25 19:03:44.237: I/ConfigService(1203): onCreate
01-25 19:03:49.340: I/ConfigService(1203): onDestroy
01-25 19:03:54.819: E/NetlinkEvent(192): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
01-25 19:04:09.828: E/NetlinkEvent(192): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
01-25 19:04:57.794: E/NetlinkEvent(192): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
01-25 19:05:12.826: E/NetlinkEvent(192): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
01-25 19:05:13.472: E/(193): invalid crash request of size 4 (from pid=4962 uid=0)
01-25 19:05:13.615: E/Diag_Lib(4977):  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 2
01-25 19:05:13.615: E/Sensors(4977): sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush failed, 9
01-25 19:05:13.616: E/Sensors(4977): sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush failed, 9
01-25 19:05:13.648: W/Sensors(4977): sns_smr_la.c(446):smr_la: smr_apps_la_thread_main is starting, fd=11, sns_smr.en_rx_msg_ptr=b6fc4a08
01-25 19:05:13.713: W/Sensors(4977): sns_sam_app.c(6827):sns_sam_reg_algo: Registering algo service 16, err 0
01-25 19:05:13.726: E/Sensors(4977): sns_debug_main.c(565):Debug Config File missing in EFS!
01-25 19:06:00.771: E/NetlinkEvent(192): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
01-25 19:06:15.788: E/NetlinkEvent(192): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
01-25 19:06:45.928: E/(193): invalid crash request of size 4 (from pid=4977 uid=0)
01-25 19:06:46.091: E/Diag_Lib(4991):  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 2
01-25 19:06:46.091: E/Sensors(4991): sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush failed, 9
01-25 19:06:46.092: E/Sensors(4991): sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush failed, 9
01-25 19:06:46.119: W/Sensors(4991): sns_smr_la.c(446):smr_la: smr_apps_la_thread_main is starting, fd=11, sns_smr.en_rx_msg_ptr=b6f2ea08
01-25 19:06:46.185: W/Sensors(4991): sns_sam_app.c(6827):sns_sam_reg_algo: Registering algo service 16, err 0
01-25 19:06:46.200: E/Sensors(4991): sns_debug_main.c(565):Debug Config File missing in EFS!
01-25 19:07:00.446: I/UsageStatsService(607): User[0] Flushing usage stats to disk
01-25 19:07:06.820: E/NetlinkEvent(192): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
01-25 19:07:21.828: E/NetlinkEvent(192): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
01-25 19:08:09.795: E/NetlinkEvent(192): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
01-25 19:08:18.400: E/(193): invalid crash request of size 4 (from pid=4991 uid=0)
01-25 19:08:18.715: E/Diag_Lib(5008):  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 2
01-25 19:08:18.717: E/Sensors(5008): sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush failed, 9
01-25 19:08:18.718: E/Sensors(5008): sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush failed, 9
01-25 19:08:18.748: W/Sensors(5008): sns_smr_la.c(446):smr_la: smr_apps_la_thread_main is starting, fd=11, sns_smr.en_rx_msg_ptr=b6ffca08
01-25 19:08:18.808: W/Sensors(5008): sns_sam_app.c(6827):sns_sam_reg_algo: Registering algo service 16, err 0
01-25 19:08:18.819: E/Sensors(5008): sns_debug_main.c(565):Debug Config File missing in EFS!
01-25 19:08:24.828: E/NetlinkEvent(192): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
01-25 19:09:12.771: E/NetlinkEvent(192): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Either `onServiceConnected` is never called, or `onServiceDisconnected` is called after `onServiceConnected` and before `doInBackground`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What could probably be happening is that `mServiceConn` instance of `ServiceConnection` connection class takes some time to connect, and until the connection is established, `mService` remains null.

To fix this, please try the following code:

```
public class AvailableCards extends Activity {

IInAppBillingService mService;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_available_cards);
    String packagename = this.getPackageName();
    TextView priceView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.availablePrice);

    ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
       @Override
       public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
           mService = null;
       }

       @Override
       public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name,
          IBinder service) {
           mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
           new GetItemList(packagename, priceView).execute();
       }
    };

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.available_cards, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}

class GetItemList extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Long> {

private String pName;
private TextView pView;

GetItemList(String packagename, TextView priceView){
    pName = packagename;
    pView = priceView;
}

@Override
protected Long doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String> ();
    skuList.add("i001");
    skuList.add("i002");
    Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
    querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);
    Bundle skuDetails = null;
    try {
        skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, pName, "inapp", querySkus);
        int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
        if (response == 0) {
           ArrayList<String> responseList
              = skuDetails.getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");
           for (String thisResponse : responseList) {
              JSONObject object;
              object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
              String sku = object.getString("productId");
              String price = object.getString("price");
              String mFirstIntermediate;
              String mSecondIntermediate;
            if (sku.equals("i001")) mFirstIntermediate = price;
              else if (sku.equals("i002")) mSecondIntermediate = price;
            pView.setText(sku + ": " + price);
           }
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException ne)  {
        Log.d("Synch Billing", "Error Null Pointer: " + ne.getMessage());
        ne.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("Synch Billing", "Error Remote: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (JSONException je) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("Synch Billing", "Error JSON: " + je.getMessage());
        je.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you Fabio. I'm new to threading, so it's baby steps for me. I *believe* your code works, with a couple of modifications. However, for some reason this morning Eclipse won't go into debug mode for me. As soon as I fix this and can step through the code to the next issue, I'll mark your answer and post what small modifications I had to make to it to get it to run. Again, thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the delay; I was on vacation. Anyway, the debugger is now working, but I'm never getting to my GetItemList class. When the debugger gets to my ServiceConnection declaration (mServiceConn) and I do Step Into, it goes to the Object.java Object() constructor and then to the end of my declaration. The debugger never goes into the declaration, so it never hits the onServiceConnected() method. Any idea why not?

Comment: Sorry for my delay; I am not 100% sure, but I think that piece of code is not running linear, then the debugger isn't going to hit the next line immediately after the line containing declaration. So, the best way to debug the flow of the program for me would be: add a breakpoint in "ServiceConnection" declaration, then another breakpoint inside the "onServiceConnected()" method. When it stops at the first breakpoint, hit the "play" button and let the program run freely, and it will then hit the next break point insde the "onServiceConnected" method

Comment: Thanks for your response. I should've posted this, but I figured out the problem. I wasn't binding to the service (i.e., using the bindService method). Once I added that, all is well. Thanks again.

Comment: You shouldn't have mServiceConn defined in the constructor as you won't be able to unbind it in the onDestroy(). _"Remember to unbind from the In-app Billing service when you are done with your Activity. If you don’t unbind, the open service connection could cause your device’s performance to degrade."_ [Docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html)